# I want to be able to use commands and command blocks

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I only have minecraft for a playstation 4 and I want to be able to put furniture in my house without using the mod. I know there is a way to do so, but the ps4 does not have command blocks so that I can do it. How can I get command blocks on the ps4?

Comment: If the PS4 doesn’t offer command blocks, then you can’t get command blocks in the PS4.

Answer (score 2):

Minecraft PS4 edition does not have commands at all. It is therefore impossible to get a command blocks of any type on that version.